# What does “you dropped them keys” mean?

Tags: expressions, slang, music

I was listening a song called To The Left from Beyonce.
There is a part that she sings: 
“Because you was untrue
Rolling her around in the car that I bought you
Baby you dropped them keys
Hurry up before your taxi leaves”.

Could you guys explain me what does she mean?
If she was talking about the car keys, it shouldn’t be “you dropped its keys”

Comment: It's just poetically licensed bad grammar.  It should also be "because you **were** untrue", and probably "baby, you dropped **the** keys" or "**those** keys".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lyrics interpretation is mostly a matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring the context for the moment - native speakers tend to substitute "those" with "them" quite frequently.

It means the same thing, but it is very informal.

Eg - "Are you going to eat those apples?" becomes "Are you going to eat them apples?". Both sentences mean the same thing, the second one is what you would say to your best friend and not to a stranger.

You're on the right track with "its keys" but she's referencing them indirectly. Grammatically her wording should have been "you dropped those keys".

Comment: I wouldn't say  that it is informal, but that it is in a non-standard (but common) variety of English. I would never use _them_ for _those_ - it's not in the variety of English I was brought up to speak - but for many English speakers, it is normal.

Comment: @ColinFine well by process of elimination it has to be informal. It’s definitely not formal. I also use it every day in Irish English when talking to friends, I know it’s not technically correct though - hence the informality.

Comment: OK, I agree that it is not formal. But my point was that, while it is not grammatical in any standard variety of English, it is normal in several non-standard varieties.

Comment: @ColinFine that’s fine, Colin.